# Declaring types of argument variables outside the function headers in C

Tags: c++, c

I was going through the [list](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/quake/public/code/predicates.c) of functions written by Jon Shewchuk for basic geometric
predicates when I came across functions like `doubleprint` which purports to print the bit representation of a double.  It is defined as

```
void doubleprint(number)
double number;
{
  unsigned long long no;
  unsigned long long sign, expo;
  .
  .
  printf("_%d  (%d)", exponent, exponent - 1 - bottomi);
  }
}
```

I would have imagined the function header would be  `void doubleprint(double number)`. Strangely 
the above function seems to compile with gcc 4.8.2.

Is this some special construct in C or is it equal to the "traditional" way of defining functions?

Comment: Yes, that is the K&R C way of writing a function definition.